# Using Image Literal for arrays In Xcode 14?

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, image

I'm following a tutorial and on the tutorial when they click the icon circled in red, images pop up to choose from. However, when I double click the 2nd icon nothing happens.

[image]

I used the #imageLiteral() and the first icon images pop up but not for any following that first image. This Is Xcode version 14.

Comment: This is a bug in Xcode. It is remembering which image you select. It's just not showing the selected image in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
   //To set image literals into the array you can use the below variable array.
    var imageLiteralArray = [
        UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "card1"),
        UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "card2")
    ]
    //to assign array to image view you can use the below code 
    imageView.image = imageLiteralArray[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same using imageLiteral() but give a space after the coma(,) and try it will work.

@IBAction func rollButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

```
    [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceOne"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceTwo"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceThree")
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34679027)

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned, some images will show once you double click on the placeholder. The images that aren't resolved most likely have a scale suffix in their name like so: `#imageLiteral("img@2x.png")`.

Once you get rid of the suffix--i.e. the "@2x" part--the inline image preview will show: `#imageLiteral("img.png")`

One tip about fixing it: Xcode will not convert the inline preview to text even when you delete some letters, so do a search with "@2x" and replace it with an empty string.

[image: Find and replace]